# How do I switch off inherited permissions on report folder (IcCube)

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I am trying to give access to differents roles / folders as following :

I have 3 roles :

- MyCompanyPole1
- MyCompanyPole2
- MyCompanyAllPoles

And 3 Directories containing reports :

- Docs > Web Docs > ic3-report > data > shared > MyCompany > Templates > Pole1
- Docs > Web Docs > ic3-report > data > shared > MyCompany > Templates > Pole2
- Docs > Web Docs > ic3-report > data > shared > MyCompany > Templates > AllPoles

How should I define the roles permissions to :

- deny Pole2 directory to role MyCompanyPole1
- deny Pole1 directory to role MyCompanyPole2
- allow MyCompanyAllPoles to access AllPoles, Pole1 & Pole2

I tried to use the "- inherit" in the definition file without success

```
--   switch off inherited permissions (file only):
--   - inherit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no deny and -inherit applies to file only. You'll have to explicitly setup the permissions for each folders:

```
:Templates/Pole1
    + [MyCompanyPole1]
    + [MyCompanyAllPoles]

:Templates/Pole2
    + [MyCompanyPole2]
    + [MyCompanyAllPoles]

:Templates/AllPoles
    + [MyCompanyAllPoles]
```

Comment: I see the principle but am not sure where I should put this code (in Templates's permissions ? or in it's parent ?)  Furthermore, I get an error when trying such a code : définition des permissions non valide [ligne:15] : syntax error: +/- expressions are expected (UX_DOCS_PERMS_ERROR)

Comment: @BertrandMiot in the Docs, select the folder, and use the top right icon for Permissions and add for example: +[MyCompanyPole1] READ

Comment: This is what I always do but, in this case, MyCompanyPole1 role has already access to Pole2 because of it's rights on the parent (MyCompany)

Comment: you would need to remove from the parent and assign directly in the children